# Post Photos and Videos on Facebook Wall

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to post Photos, Videos on Facebook walls from my `MVC` app. I'm getting below error
`(OAuthException - #2500) An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.`

Please help me. Please find below code which I'm using.

```
  string appID = string.Empty;
  string appSecretCode = string.Empty;
  appID = "<<application Id>>";
  appSecretCode = "<<app secretcode>>";
  var fb = new FacebookClient();
  dynamic result = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new
  {
      client_id = appID,
      client_secret = appSecretCode,
      grant_type = "client_credentials",
      scope = "publish_stream"
  });
  string accessToken = result.access_token;
  var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
  var postparameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
  var media = new FacebookMediaObject
  {
      FileName = @"Bday.jpg",
      ContentType = "image/jpeg"
  };
  byte[] img = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Bday.jpg");
  media.SetValue(img);
  postparameters["source"] = media;
  postparameters["access_token"] = result.access_token;
  var result1 = client.Post(String.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/photos", "<<User ID>>"), postparameters);
```

Comment: @Junaith Still my issue is not resolved. Please help me to promote this question if u have any option for that.

Comment: Heyla, did you ever find out how to do this?

Comment: This issue got resolved for me. for postparameters["access_token"] property we need to assign access token which will get populated in the Graph API Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate access token from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer and try:

```
required AcccountId, pageid

dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.message =modelList.message;
parameters.subject = modelList.subject;
parameters.account_id = modelList.AcccountId;

imageBytes =  byte[] of image

parameters.source = new FacebookMediaObject{
    ContentType = imageType,
    FileName = Url
}.SetValue(imageBytes);

client.Post(pageid+ "/photos", parameters);
```

Hope it will help.